# PHP check if "multidimensional array(array([key]=>value))" values are empty

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have this array I am posting in Laravel from my view to my controller, and I am trying to check if there is any values inside the array.
The array is initialized and sent to the view and inside the view I have a table with inputs to fill, if the user doesn't fill the table and submits the form, the array will come back as following:

```
Array
(
[51] => Array
    (
        [5] => 
        [2] => 
        [8] => 
    )

[78] => Array
    (
        [18] => 
        [23] => 
        [21] => 
    )
)
```

for clarification and communication:

```
array(
   [key1]=>array
           (
              [key1_1]=>value
           )
)
```

and I want to check if all of `value` are empty or not which they are in this example, it would be something similar to `empty($array)` for 1 dimensional arrays.

I have tried `array_filter()` but it doesn't serve if the value is inside a key inside a key inside an array.

I know I can use `foreach` to enter to `key1` and then `foreach` again to enter `key1_1`  and recursively check if the value is null or not and return false and break the loop whenever a value is not null.

But is there any other way or a method in PHP that allows checking those values? something similar to `empty($array)` but goes inside the array and checks `value` only? or something that has the logic of `empty(array_filter(array_filter($array)))`?

or there is no other way except recursively check each value manually by using `foreach`?

**NOTE: I am using Laravel 5.5, PHP 7.1.9**

**NOTE: I am not trying if find a specific value is null, I am asking if there is a built-in method in PHP or a simpler method than the one I use to check if the values are all null or not.**

Comment: You can try array_sum, if == 0 - empty

Comment: Is it explicitly always a *two dimensional array*, or could it be more or less nested than that?

Comment: @deceze it is explicitly always two dimensional array as in the example, it will never be more or less nested than that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_map('array_filter', $array)` will remove all inner empty values, bringing the array to something like:

```
[
    51 => [],
    78 => [
        18 => 'not empty'
    ]
]
```

Then `array_filter` that again to remove all empty arrays. In summary:

```
if (!array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array))) {
    echo 'The array is completely empty';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this could be to use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and pass an empty array as the start value. Then in the callback function use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

At the end you could use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the empty entries and then [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the items in the final array.

```
$arrays = [
    51 => [
        5 => "",
        2 => "",
        8 => "77"
    ],
    78 => [
        18 => "",
        23 => "99",
        21 => ""
    ]
];

$result = array_reduce($arrays, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry = array_merge($carry, $item);
    return $carry;
}, []);
```

[Test with all empty values](https://3v4l.org/8v8Pm)

[Test with values](https://3v4l.org/ItbBQ)

Comment: your solution works, but I am gonna mark @deceze 's answer as the correct one since it is more accurate with less lines.

Answer (score -1):

This should work if you are only trying to get the number of empty slots in an array.

```
$myArray = ["bob", "fred", "bill", "mary", "", "jane", ""];

$count = 0;
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value) {


if(!$value) {
$count++;
}


}
echo $count;
```

Comment: `empty` should be replaced with `!$value` here. Don't use `empty` where a boolean test will do.